# How to get the name of static method in a class?

Tags: typescript

I print many logs in the static method and I want to use the method name as context. But I don't want to declare a `context` variable and assign the function/method name to it.

I want to use the context by accessing the method name. Not only in a class static method, but also in every function.

Here is my try:

```js
class CloudFunction {
  public static parse() {

    console.log(this.name); // CloudFunction
    console.log(CloudFunction.parse.name); // get nothing here


    // Don't want to declare `context` variable and assign method name to it.
    const context = 'parse';
    logger.debug('a log', { context, arguments: 'pubsubMessage' });

    //... many logs use this context

    // want the better way like this:
    // const self = this;
    // logger.error(new Error('bad'), {context: self.name })
  }
}


CloudFunction.parse();
```

None of them work. Can I use `reflect` way to get it? I am not sure `reflect` can do this.

**update**

Here is my result:

```
☁  DL-Toolkits [master] npx ts-node /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/ts-codelab/src/class/get-static-method-name/index.ts
CloudFunction
```

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the name of the method, or do I misunderstand anything?

```
class ClassWithStaticMethod {
  static staticMethod() {
    console.log('1: ' + ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod.name); // output: '1: staticMethod'
    return ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod.name;
  }
}

console.log('2: ' + ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod()); // output: '2: staticMethod'
```

[Code sample](https://playcode.io/309861?tabs=console&script.js&output)

Comment: Apparently it all depends on the compilation target: [play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20ClassWithStaticMethod%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20staticMethod()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod.name)%3B%20%2F%2F%20output%3A%20staticMethod%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod.name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod())%3B%20%2F%2F%20output%3A%20staticMethod)

Comment: Seems like zerkms answer is the right hint, but sadly I have no idea why, or how this behavior achieves. I will let this answer be at its place for research reasons. As far as an answer is provided I will delete it!

Comment: slideshowp2 as zerkms mentioned it this behavior seems to be reasoned by the compilation target. Try the Code sample link for a running example.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the public access modifier before the static method.

```
class CloudFunction {
  static parse() {
    console.log(this.name); // CloudFunction
    console.log(CloudFunction.parse.name); // get nothing here

    const context = 'parse';
  }
}


CloudFunction.parse();
```

This code works without access modifier

Comment: Is there a reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no straightforward way of getting this.

Create a new static variable to store `current` function name, and use a decorators to change this variable when a function will be call.

```
function changeContextName(target: object, propertyName: string, propertyDesciptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  let method = propertyDesciptor.value;
  propertyDesciptor.value = function() {
    // let prevMethod = this.context; // backup previous method name
    this.context = propertyName;
    method.apply(this, arguments);
    // this.context = prevMethod; // restore previous method name
  };
}


class CloudFunction {
  public static context: string;

  @changeContextName
  public static parse() {

    console.log({context: this.context});
  }

  @changeContextName
  public test() {
    console.log({ context: CloudFunction.context});
  }
}

CloudFunction.parse();
(new CloudFunction()).test();
```